# Change onclick handler of the element added dynamically after the page has loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following DOM structure.

```
<div class="purchase-section">
   <div class="purchase">
      <input type="submit" id="add-to-cart" class="btn" name="add" value="Add to Cart"> <span class="rc-or">Or</span>
      <button class="btn rc-button" id="btn-buy-now" onclick="event.preventDefault(); window.location='https://example.com?productId=681';">Buy Now - 3 installment</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

The button element is added by a script which runs after the page has loaded. I need to change the onclick handler for this button. I tried following but it doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.purchase-section').on('change', '.purchase', function(){
    $("#btn-buy-now")[0].onclick = null;
    $("#btn-buy-now").click(function() { alert("done") });
  });
});
```

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Why are you using a `change` function for a `click` event? Simply write a new click function, and use `off()` if you need to remove the previous click function. Also, there's no change event on a div.

Comment: @isherwood How will I bind the off() event to the button element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$("#btn-buy-now").removeAttr("onclick");` to remove `onclick` completely and then delegate event to dynamically added element.

```
$("static_parent").on("event", "dynamic_element", function () {
});

$(".purchase").on("click", "#btn-buy-now", function () {
  /* code */
});
```

Comment: Are you sure that removing an attribute also removes the attached event functions? I'd use `off()`.

Comment: @isherwood it does remove the function by removing attribute. http://jsfiddle.net/nv36wd7L/

Comment: `off()` will not work, as it isn't added with `on()`... better to register the original click event by using `on()` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".purchase-section").find("#btn-buy-now").removeAttr('onclick');
   $(".purchase-section").find("#btn-buy-now").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      alert("done");
   });
});
```

However, it depends on when this element is loaded.  You will need to ensure your button is already in the DOM *before* this script executes, otherwise this may not be effective.